# Does Game Center require Sprite Kit?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift4, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I created a quiz game in **Swift 4.2** that was NOT built using `SpriteKit`. All of the current resources that I can find about **Game Center** integration involve `SpriteKit`. Thus, I am trying to figure out if I need to make the game in `SpriteKit` in order to use **Game Center**? If not, can someone point me to current, relevant resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need sprite kit, what you need is Game Kit framework, it's the framework that apple provide for you be able to have this connection.
Try a look here first, for the apple documentation: 
[Apple GameKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit)
And after looking at this look here for a easier tutorial: [Implementing Game Center - Game Kit](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/game-center-and-leaderboards-for-your-ios-app--cms-27488)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info.